# visual studio 2013 : create installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation

i want to create my first installer using visual studio 2013, i have installed the ext like the following picture[image]

i have followed the instruction [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2014/04/24/visual-studio-2013-installer-projects-ndash-hello-world-installer.aspx) and i don't have the menus, 
like the following picture
[image]

and i cant find any instruction on the [microsoft](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d) page

how can i build the installer ?

answer :

i forgot to check the dropdown project type
[image]

Comment: Glad you edited your question to include the problem solver. It's bound to help people running into the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Setup Wizard Project to create an .MSI file. You can specify what files and actions the installer should preform during and after install. 
Once you have done that, you can "Build" the project and out comes an .MSI and another installer type (I thought it was a normal .exe).

Just checking, you used this extension right? https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you're looking to use the installer you specifically linked, but an easy way is to use a ClickOnce installer. Refer to this MSDN link for an easy explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx

Comment: thanks, i need like "MSI Installer" or "Installshield Installer" or something like that, i am developing desktop base, so i don't have any idea about the location to publish the application